# Is it possible to update(overwrite) node id of a page content in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am doing migration from drupal 6 to drupal 7. However, I migrated all the page contents successfully, I want to keep the same nodeid from my previous version.

The below piece of code did it. But i need to update each and every table. Even though it works, I want to confirm like Is there any function available to do this process. something like node_update ?

Example: After migration i want to update the node id of a page from 123 to 12. So that it should update all the tables where node id 123 has been referred to 12.

### Code:

```
public function postImport() {
  $original_node_data = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')
        ->select('node', 'nd')
        ->fields('nd', array('nid', 'type', 'title'))
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();    

  foreach ($original_node_data as $ori_nd_dta) {
    $ori_nd_id = $ori_nd_dta->nid;
    $oti_nd_title = $ori_nd_dta->title;
    $duplicate_node_data = Database::getConnection('default', 'default')
          ->select('node', 'nd')
          ->fields('nd', array('nid', 'title'))
          ->condition('title', $oti_nd_title)
          ->execute()
          ->fetchAll();
    foreach ($duplicate_node_data as $dup_data) {
      $dup_nd_id = $dup_data->nid;
    }
    $update_node = db_update('node')
          ->fields(array('nid' => $ori_nd_id))
          ->condition('nid', $dup_nd_id)
          ->execute();
    $update_node_rev = db_update('node_revision')
          ->fields(array('nid' => $ori_nd_id))
          ->condition('nid', $dup_nd_id)
          ->execute();
    .......
    .......
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the node table is empty.

I think people use UUID for this issue.